# eBird hotspot api Android Studio google maps implementation

Tags: java, android-studio

I am trying to display the hotspot markers on a google maps fragment in my android app. These hotspots are coming from an eBird api. api key: dclt54iuokkf. GET: [https://api.ebird.org/v2/ref/hotspot/geo?lat={{lat}}&lng={{lng}}](https://api.ebird.org/v2/ref/hotspot/geo?lat=%7B%7Blat%7D%7D&lng=%7B%7Blng%7D%7D). Can anyone please help me implement this. Thanks

At first I wanted to try to put the locations individually but it is a lot of locations.